# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface" when using Checkstyle Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, ibm-rational

I am trying to use the eclipse-cs plugin on Rational Software Architect 7.0.0.4.

I recently uninstalled the older beta2 version and installed beta3. The plug-in itself works as was previously configured. But whenever I attempt to re-configure the check rules via Windows->Preferences->Checkstyle, I get the following error:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

This occurs when I click the configure button and attempt to reconfigure a specific selected check rule on the UI.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue before and how can it be fixed?

The full error listing and stack trace is shown below:

```
Stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.setMessage(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.RuleConfigurationEditDialog.createAdvancedSection(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.RuleConfigurationEditDialog.createDialogArea(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.RuleConfigurationEditDialog.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationConfigureDialog$PageController.openModule(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationConfigureDialog$PageController.doubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDoubleSelect(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.configureCheckConfig(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor.access$6(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.config.CheckConfigurationWorkingSetEditor$PageController.doubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDoubleSelect(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

And the session data:

```
Session Data:
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Windows XP x86-32 j9vmwi3223ifx-20070323 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20070322_12058_lHdSMR
JIT  - 20070109_1805ifx3_r8
GC   - WASIFIX_2007
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.ide
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085534/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface

Answer (score 36):

Try so start Eclipse from the console/terminal with the `-clean` option.

On Windows:

```
Eclipse.exe -clean
```

On *nix:

```
./eclipse -clean
```

or if Eclipse is in your PATH

```
eclipse -clean
```

This will clear your plug-ins cache, maybe it solves the issue.

Comment: Worked for me. though I had to manually remove one plugin folder as the clean wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

My simple guess would be that the version of Eclipse that RSA 7.0 is based on is missing some methods that your version of check style is wanting.
RSA 7.5 uses Eclipse 3.4, and I've been very happy with it.

Comment: Thank you, the -clean worked for me in fixing the same error.