# Problems occured when invoking code from Plugin:"org.eclipse.core.resources"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, compiler-errors

I am getting the error while cleaning the project. I am attaching the error log file. Please help me to solve the problem. Thanks.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2013-06-18 15:15:06.695
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.traverse(ClassFile.java:7530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.completeCodeAttribute(ClassFile.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.internalGenerateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.generateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2013-06-18 15:15:07.090
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2013-06-18 15:15:07.090
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'GetTheMeaningApp'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.traverse(ClassFile.java:7530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.completeCodeAttribute(ClassFile.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.internalGenerateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.generateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2013-06-18 15:28:35.312
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.traverse(ClassFile.java:7530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.completeCodeAttribute(ClassFile.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.internalGenerateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.generateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2013-06-18 15:28:35.524
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2013-06-18 15:28:35.525
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'GetTheMeaningApp'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.traverse(ClassFile.java:7530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.completeCodeAttribute(ClassFile.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.internalGenerateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.generateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2013-06-18 15:29:36.050
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.traverse(ClassFile.java:7530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.completeCodeAttribute(ClassFile.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.internalGenerateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.generateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2013-06-18 15:29:36.498
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2013-06-18 15:29:36.498
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'GetTheMeaningApp'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.traverse(ClassFile.java:7530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.completeCodeAttribute(ClassFile.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.internalGenerateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.generateCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Your problem nearly match with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085534/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface