# Parsing error processing resource path struts-config.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, struts2

I have a Dynamic Web Project Java in Eclipse, and I always could deploy this project with glassfish in localhost. I recently got a new PC, and I pull the repository, so everything is the same in my new PC, but now, I get this error when I try to deploy the application:

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/3dembenchmark]PWC1396: Servlet /3dembenchmark threw load() exceptionjavax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path /WEB-INF/classes/config/struts/struts-config.xml
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.handleConfigException(ActionServlet.java:769)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:743)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I am using the same Java compiler (openjdk 1.6) and I think everything is with the same configuration. The file struts-config.xml hasn't been changed, and in my other laptop is working.
Permissions in all the files and directories are also the same.

Where is the problem? What else can I check?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the whole log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085534/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface/13085848#13085848

Comment: I added the whole log. @Roman C, is not a problem with .classpath or .project, thank you.

Comment: Finally I could solve these annoying problem. I had my Eclipse _Standard_ with all the plugins that I needed, but something should be wrong configured, and the only thing that worked was to reinstall Eclipse, but the one named "for _Web Developers_". I hope this helps someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

In struts-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
           "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
              "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
               "struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
```

and download the struts-config_1.3.dtd from the below location and keep it inside the WEB-INF folder.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/struts-site/master/source/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd
```

Note: It's also working for other struts-config_1_1.dtd and struts-config_1_2.dtd, In my local system i tried it for struts-config_1_3.dtd