# Hibernate configuration to create hbm and POJO

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm following [this](http://javafws.blogspot.in/2013/04/generate-hbm-files-pojo-classes-in-eclipse.html) tutorial to generate hbm and POJO files where I am stuck creating hibernate launch configuration . I was able to create it for the 1st time somehow, but after that I am constantly facing error-

```
Message: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

Exception Stack Trace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jpt/jpa/core/JpaFacet
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.EclipseLaunchConsoleConfigurationPreferences.getProjectOverrides(EclipseLaunchConsoleConfigurationPreferences.java:228)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.EclipseLaunchConsoleConfigurationPreferences.getProperties(EclipseLaunchConsoleConfigurationPreferences.java:163)
at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$3.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:240)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildWith(ConsoleConfiguration.java:237)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationJavaClasspathTab.isValid(ConsoleConfigurationJavaClasspathTab.java:97)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.refresh(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:473)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.updateButtons(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:193)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.updateLaunchConfigurationDialog(AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.java:113)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationTab.access$0(ConsoleConfigurationTab.java:1)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConsoleConfigurationTab$ChangeListener.modifyText(ConsoleConfigurationTab.java:24)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConnectionProfileCtrl.notifyModifyListeners(ConnectionProfileCtrl.java:366)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.ConnectionProfileCtrl$3.selectionChanged(ConnectionProfileCtrl.java:276)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:163)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2171)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1202)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1231)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:408)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1154)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:213)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog(DebugUITools.java:661)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog(DebugUITools.java:638)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.AddConfigurationAction.doAddConfiguration(AddConfigurationAction.java:79)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.AddConfigurationAction.run(AddConfigurationAction.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

I tried so many times without success. I have noticed that if I follow steps as  create hbm,  set classpath, set database connection and lastly project name, then error doesn't show up untill I open configuration file. Am i missing any plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085534/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface 
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776334/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface-when-usin

Comment: @KarimTawfik I don't think so. Compare Stack Trace and where they face problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know the stack traces are different, but both problems related to eclipse plugin.

Comment: are you still getting the exception?