# Deployment Assembly: The currently displayed page contains invalid values

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I imported a Java Web application from Sourceforge, and I did three working weeks efforts to get rid off all red crosses attached to the project name and packages, but now I couldn't make the application run on my Eclipse & tomcat6 developing environment. In project properties when I tried to set the Deployment Assembly, the dialog box showed: the currently displayed page contains invalid values. And in the error log, I found when I click the Deployment Assembly, The following error message was showed:

Error

```
Wed Jan 09 10:25:16 CST 2013
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualFolder.getFirstTaggedResource(VirtualFolder.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getDefaultDeploymentDescriptorFolder(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.ui.JavaEEDeploymentAssemblyAdvancedSectionBuilder.(JavaEEDeploymentAssemblyAdvancedSectionBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.ui.J2EEModuleDependenciesPropertyPage.getAdvancedSectionBuilder(J2EEModuleDependenciesPropertyPage.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.ui.J2EEModuleDependenciesPropertyPage.(J2EEModuleDependenciesPropertyPage.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.internal.WebDependencyPropertyPage.(WebDependencyPropertyPage.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.internal.WebModuleDependencyPageProvider.createPages(WebModuleDependencyPageProvider.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.ui.propertypage.ModuleAssemblyRootPage.createContents(ModuleAssemblyRootPage.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.ui.propertypage.ModuleAssemblyRootPage.createControl(ModuleAssemblyRootPage.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1502)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I googled many times , but I cannot find the solutions. Can anyone give a favor to let the Deployment Assembly work? I think this is the key why my app cannot run. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem in Juno

Comment: @RuntimeError, have you solved this please ?

Answer (score 12):

eclipse -clean didn't fix it for me.  My workaround:  In eclipse delete the project (don't delete on disk).  Then in the filesystem delete .project .classpath and .settings/*   Then in eclipse, same workspace,  create new webproject with same name as the old one.  It created the project and found all my source. Now Deployment Assembly works again!  After that, I updated build path to have the proper project and lib dependencies.

Comment: I had a similar problem for a C/C++ project (uses CDT) and this comment solved the issue for me. In my particular case, there were stale values in the .cproject file. Deleting the project in Eclipse, closing it, deleting the .project, .cproject and .settings hide files in the project directory, starting Eclipse again and re-creating the project worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I just imported the project again after deleting .project, .classpath and .setting/*, and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Just for the record, eocanha's solution does not work for me :-( Although I admit that I cannto understand why. It sounds like it _should_ work. Oh, well, I will just step back aversion, to 4.5.1

Comment: I also deleted `.metadata`, but that did not help :-(

Answer (score 6):

Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492924). If `eclipse -clean` won't help, then probably something is wrong with your project's specific settings. I would suggest you to examine every file inside `.settings/` directory.

I know this is not a ready-to-go solution, but may be at least a starting point.

Comment: don't forget to restart eclipse after changing the files in .settings directory

Comment: Worked for me: had to edit `org.eclipse.wst.common.componnent` file

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue as well. It was caused by me deleting another project on which my current project was dependent. I fixed the issue by opening the file `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` in the .settings folder and deleting the dependency. This fixed the issues and I was able to edit the deployment assembly.

Section I removed: (utility.jar is the name of my offending jar)

```
   <dependent-module archiveName="utility.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/utility/utility">
        <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
    </dependent-module>
```

Someone else I work with was able to fix it by deleting the jar from their build path.

Hope this helps anyone that hits this issue.

Comment: I opened the file and add following lines:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="<your project name>">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/db"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>

Answer (score 0):

Delete  .project .classpath and .settings then cleate a new(temporally) workspace 
import your project in the new workspace, this will generate new  .project .classpath and .settings files. Then open the old workspace again and issue is fixed. You can delete the temporally workspace if you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Please check this file ".settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component" under .settings folder which maps to the deployment assembly in the UI.Please check "wb-module" tag and clean up the wb-resource items inside it if present.

This file will be visible in navigator view in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same state in different situation after adding a *Source* (a folder) and trying to modify the *Deploy Path*. So, got the same error message: **Deployment Assembly: The currently displayed page contains invalid values**. Unfortunately the ideas above did not help and many seemed to suggest bigger delete/re-install operations to a seemingly small config issue.

Unfortunately, at the given error state Eclipse (Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)) did not allow go use GUI to correct things... so what I did next.

I found out that the entries tagged:  `<wb-resource .... />` in the **xml-file org.eclipse.wst.common.component** in **{workspace}/{project}/.settings** -folder had incomplete entry of wb-resources. I needed to have something like this included in there:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/web" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
```

The  wegb-row was incomplete and src-containing-row was missing completely. This file/location has been targeted and identified to be potentially corrupt/invalid also in earlier answers. Fixing this file did not let me get GUI work, yet. Next I had to delete couple of rows from a plugin history.

In **{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history** -folder I located the *newest folders* and **deleted folders that contained the changes related to *Deployment Assembly***.

After this restarted Eclipse and I could use the GUI for configurations again! **I did no need to delete/re-install project** (I wanted to avoid re-installing project due to lots of configuration). I hope this helps someone else running into the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem, and I realized it started just after I installed into my Neon.1a Eclipse a certain old plugin, aimed to versions 3.x.

So I uninstalled that plugin, and the problem dissapeared without changing my workspace in any.

(Just to complete the information, I'll say that the "culprit" was the Randalco EHP plugin, but I suppose any old version plugin might be suspicious too).

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

to eclipse.ini solved problem for me on Fedora 33 GNOME