# How to -clean start STS on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I want to execute

```
./eclipse -clean
```

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492924/953327).

However, I am running STS installed as an application on Mac.

What is the equivalent command for Mac users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command I was looking for appears to be

```
open -a /Applications/STS.app --args -clean
```

Comment: It has to be STS.app, but edits must be 6 characters at least %-)