# Error "the currently displayed page contains invalid values" in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I go to *ADT* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* I get the error message:

> the currently displayed page contains invalid values

Then on the main *Appearance* menu I see a *Themes* drop down menu which doesn't work. I am trying to change the overall theme of Eclipse, I was able to change the coding window with the theme plugin but that doesn't change the rest of the applications theme.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776334/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface-when-usin/3492924#3492924 <br>
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I fixed it by it by creating a new workspace and by importing in it the Android Project