# Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.MavenImages

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When I try to open the run configuration for my newly imported maven project an error message pops up:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.MavenImages
```

```
eclipse.buildId=4.12.0.I20190605-1800
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\me\...\project\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2020-09-02 11:33:42.746

org.eclipse.jface
Error
Wed Sep 02 11:34:39 CEST 2020
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.MavenImages
    at org.eclipse.m2e.ui.internal.launch.MavenLaunchMainTab.getImage(MavenLaunchMainTab.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.showInstanceTabsFor(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.lambda$4(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog$4.selectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.lambda$0(StructuredViewer.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3919)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3550)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.lambda$1(DebugUITools.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
```

I tried to clean the plugins cache as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492924/3014199

Now I get

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/jface/resource/ResourceLocator
```

With stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/resource/ResourceLocator
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.MavenImages.doCreateDescriptor(MavenImages.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.MavenImages.createDescriptor(MavenImages.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.MavenImages.<clinit>(MavenImages.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.ui.internal.launch.MavenLaunchMainTab.getImage(MavenLaunchMainTab.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.showInstanceTabsFor(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.lambda$4(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog$4.selectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.lambda$0(StructuredViewer.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3919)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3550)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.lambda$1(DebugUITools.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceLocator cannot be found by org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui_1.15.0.20200305-1308
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 65 more
```

None of `.project`, `.settings/`, `.classpath` is on the git index, they were all generated from my machine.

Something similar happens when I open pom.xml I get
`Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml.MvnImages`
and `org/eclipse/jface/resource/ResourceLocator` as before.

Comment: Your Eclipse is pretty old (you are four releases behind). Please do not waste time by using outdated software.

Comment: The JavaDoc in ResourceLocator says it was added in JFace 3.17 - which is in Eclipse 4.13 - but you have Eclipse 4.12. It looks like the maven m2e plugin is from a newer release.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you! I upgraded to eclipse 4.16 and the problem was no more.